# Apache Cordova supported iOS version

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I'm considering to make an app with Apache Cordova.

Since iOS 10 will be released shortly, I'd like to make the app compatible with iOS 10.

Doea anyone know how can I check the supported iOS versions in each Cordova releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Cordova explicitly states which operating system versions it is compatible with, but it seems that as long as you're on IOS 8+, Cordova should work.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html
(Second paragraph in the "Requirements and Support" section)

For a more general reference:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/

Comment: From the first link: "The device must have at least iOS 8 installed, the minimum iOS version supported as of Cordova 4.0.0. Supported devices include iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5C, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone SE, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad Air, iPad Air 2, iPad Pro, iPad Mini, iPad Mini 2, iPad Mini 3, iPod Touch 5th gen and iPod Touch 6th gen or later."